# When I log typeof an IIFE to the console, it is an object instead of a function, why?

Tags: javascript, iife

I have an IIFE that returns an object. In my app.js file, which I add to a script tag in index.html, I log to the console typeof my IIFE and it is an object. Shouldn't it be a function? Why is typeof returning an object?

Here is my IIFE in app.js:

```
var UIController = (function() {

  var DOMstrings = {
    inputType: '.add__type',
    description: '.add__description',
    value: '.add__value',
    addBtn: '.add__btn'
  };

  return {
    getInput: function() {
      // return an object containing all values from UI elements
      return {
        type: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputType).value, // will be either income or expense
        description: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.description).value, // description of transaction
        value: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.value).value // value of transaction
      };
    },
    getDOMStrings: function() {
      return DOMstrings;
    }
  };

})();

console.log(typeof UIController);
```

Comment: I don't understand. You're using the term "IIFE", which makes it sound like you *do* understand what this code is; but then you ask why you're getting an object instead of a function, which makes it sound like you *don't* understand what this code is. What do you think an IIFE is? Why would you expect to get a function?

Comment: I understand what it does, but why is the typeof UIController an object instead of a function? If I wrote a function expression and logged its type to the console, it would be a function, not an object, so why am I getting object in this case?

Comment: Why does `var x = "foo".length; typeof x` return `number` when `"foo"` is a `string`?

Comment: The point of IIFE is that it is *immediately* executed. Ask yourself: what does your IIFE return when it is immediately executed? You already gave the answer in your first sentence. It is an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIFE stands for “immediately invoked function expression.” In other words, *an expression created by invoking a function*. *Invoking* a function means to call the function and produce a result. The value of an IIFE is the result of calling (invoking) the function, not the function itself.

In your example, the variable `UIController` is assigned the result of calling a function. Your function returned an object with two properties. The object is assigned to `UIController`. So `typeof UIController` produces `object` as expected.

Comment: Ok makes good sense now. Thank you for your noncritical answer.

Comment: Quite alright. It's not at all obvious and easy to get confused with this.

Answer (score 0):

**REMEMBER Immediately Invoked FUNCTION EXPRESSION FUNCTION (IIFE)  are functions whose variables cannot
be accessed outside the function & you cannot call that
function explicitly(this will give error)  **

*here is a simple code to clear concept of IIFE.
this function just prints hey & do not have any return value *

```
var run=(function(){
  console.log("HEY");
  
})();
run(); //error
console.log(run);  HEY
console.log(typeof(run));  undefined
```

*Below IIFE functions  returns the value *

```
var run=(function(){
 return 1;
  
})();
run(); //error
console.log(run);  5
console.log(typeof(run));  number
```